# Use TypeScript to describe a Proxy object that changes its property types on assignment

Tags: typescript

**The Setup**

Describing how a proxy object works to the TypeScript compiler has proven a bit challenging. Take for example the case of a Proxy with a setter that transforms any objects in the input to recursively proxy them as well, it would be really great for TypeScript to understand this and allow a direct assignment instead of needing to first coerce the final recursive proxied object. Here's an example, it's also [running on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrALYAcA2EDyARgFYQJjIDeAUMsgNqgAmEAHgFzIDOYUoA5gF1OcEAE9qAX2rUwYrCgAKUAPasxRUuQA8AFQB8yALxVaDANLJQyANYQxKmMl3Dn9c4ORtIIJlzSYuAQkZBQA-MjKahohOrrugoac8R5SyABkpnR0wFxR6py8AK4QUjIwRSDkwCogyAhQEHCQ%20WJ6Xqw%20fgHYeJqh%20gAUKiTJAJScrf1xhjR0CLU8yFiq6tMUJusAdA1NkMMkADRUkmNmMCpQyIMLIEt2YlZ1I8RjWdkr0ev0D54mg3IFI5kC8fvY-kYTAByF6hKFvCK7ZoQVoHYhgsSCN6cUG-MzSMyNMBFKB1EAQADukVWYkGnzWsTAxzm2X4EAogy2XLgUH4XDeLOyyAA9MLuCoMCguMAWF4YDBQv4ABbQFAKKBKuBYLhmIW3LgqPBbHAqfiDAAGCrACCV1gAbnAcCVkBcrgASSg8vn0ABMgkk5rOQroRJJdQAShAYHhyFs2WBOdzefyANy65CSQ7prjs65gL3s46fdVyY4Op0QAXpvWLCg5sC6FTGPPyCDA8vOyHQ2HkKEZTIAQg7EC2uVaCPqjWRqOH2OQw%20r2VDpOQkejoS29YBBaZy1UJbEx3rjaD2WkdFOZWo%20oo9OAECYzaRLRpgxZkE6nChKpwJuQFMuHAmChLM6HJHgH04QVkAwWp7E4ABmAAWABWfEpDOahRWcW1-AAqAbH8QgyDgIocysMAoX8UBgDAYBHRwR4WAQHAeQfZA4H8OBuF4ARqDvB8tg-DZkChABBEAVDAFUrmHKEsLFXRcP-WoKHwmxkGIhBSPI4SrC4ni%20BAfhjmk3J9OQfgVBUJgBwUvc1HvJghO8ZsAEYfQQmRsKU8yKWAX8VIIuyBOc8DIGc2DyUeEwPK8%20zfLwy5CP41YnK2cL2JMZ8UVfSgYLgsROBQkqM0wnzlP8wLJLU5LNJIsjSmwwxdFbUT8qi%20DkBAIoMGIqAUwzPtzJqjiuGlfgQDgQg8GQMAm0BFAoSmRltA6wrOB6vroEGyR9Hk0KMogCDHxMdbouK0rJCAA):

```
interface SimpleObject {
  [index: string]: any
}

type ProxyObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends SimpleObject ? ProxyObject<T[K]> : T[K]
} & {
    isProxy: true
}

function createProxy<T extends SimpleObject>(obj: T): ProxyObject<T> {
  const proxyObject = Object.create(obj, {})
  for (const key in obj) {
    proxyObject[key] = (typeof obj[key] === 'object') ? createProxy(obj[key]) : obj[key]
  }

  return new Proxy(proxyObject, {
    get (...args) {
      // some side effects here perhaps
      console.log(`fetchin value for ${args[2]}`)
      return Reflect.get(...args);
    },
    set (target, property, value) {
        const setTo = (typeof value === 'object' && !value.isProxy) ? createProxy(value) : value
        return Reflect.set(target, property, setTo)
    }
  })
}

const proxied = createProxy({
  text: 'hello world',
  nested: {
    money: 345
  }
})

// This works because it's initially declared as a string
proxied.text = 'Another value'
// This wont work because text is a string, this is good!
// proxied.text = 123

// This will work!
proxied.nested.money = 123

// This works
proxied.nested = createProxy({ money: 555 })

// This will not work because
// > Type '{ money: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ProxyObject<{ money: number; }>'
proxied.nested = { money: 555 }
```

**The Problem**

Ideally you there would be a way to inform the TypeScript compiler that the `proxied.nested` will automatically get converted into the correct type (i.e. `ProxyObject<{ money: number}>`). You can use a union operator in the ProxyObject definition to allow this:

```
type ProxyObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends SimpleObject ? ProxyObject<T[K]> | T[K] : T[K]
} & {
    isProxy: true
}
```

But this doesn't really resolve the issue that `proxied.nested` *changes* the type on input, instead all objects in `ProxyObject` are no longer certain if they are a SimpleObject or a ProxyObject so you have to constantly sniff that out.

**The Question:**
Is there any way to tell TypeScript that this *property* can be assigned a Union (multiple types) but its value is always a single type when read?

Comment: Well, I think it is related to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2521) conversation (or a feature request). So current implementation of Typescript doesn't allow getters and setters to have different types. Allowing that is a thing but the hard part of it is how you define that type or interface. So you need at least 2 features added into Typescript.

Comment: Did some more digging on this, and found this [issue as well](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43826)

Comment: TS4.3 is out so you can almost get there, but yes, without [microsoft/TypeScript#43826](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43826) there's no way to transform an existing type.  Oh well.